# How to identify parent table data which not inserted at specific date in child table in mysql database

Tags: laravel, mysqli

I have three table `clas`,`students` and `student_attendances` this have one to many relation if any date one/more student do not input attendance data how can i identify which student is absent or do not paunch. `student_attendance` table data store by finger print device so if any student do not paunch his card or finger there is no opportunity to insert data into this table.

i have tried this code

`SELECT
    s.id, s.full_name, s.roll, a.at_date, a.in_time 
FROM 
    students s 
LEFT JOIN 
    student_attendances a 
ON 
    s.id = a.student_id and a.at_date = '2019-07-30'
LEFT JOIN
    clas c
ON
    c.id = 1` 
`clas` table structure
`id
class_name`

`students` table structure

`id.
student_name
class_id
roll_no`

`student_attendances` table structure

`id.
student_id
attendance_date
in_time
out-time`

**now my output is**

`id|full_name|roll|at_date    |in_time  |
 1 |Md Saidul|2   |2019-07-30 |10.23 am |
 2 |Md Imran |1   |2019-07-30 |9.45 am  |
 3 |Md Saidul|3   | NULL      |NULL     |
 4 |Md Asad  |4   | NULL      |NULL     |`

**actually i want to show class name also**

`id|full_name|roll|class_name|at_date    |in_time  |
 1 |Md Saidul|2   |          |2019-07-30 |10.23 am |
 2 |Md Imran |1   |          |2019-07-30 |9.45 am  |
 3 |Md Saidul|3   |          |NULL       |NULL     |
 4 |Md Asad  |4   |          |NULL       |NULL     |`

when i search the report by a specific date and class name wise if any student is absent then his in time will be null or empty as like sample table

Comment: Please Provide Some Sample Data.So that i can dig through it

Comment: and do you need to get for the present day or custom dates

Comment: @Manojkiran.A `id
full_name
roll
at_date
in_time
1
Md Saidul
2
2019-07-30
10.23 am
2
Md Imran
1
2019-07-30
9.45 am
3
Md Saidul
3
NULL
NULL
4
Md Asad
4
NULL
NULL
`

Comment: please add it in your question its not clear in comment

Comment: @Manojkiran.A i have also update my question

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

`SELECT * FROM students as s`

`left join`

`student_attendances  as a`

`on s.id=a.id`

`WHERE a.at_date = ''`

or

`WHERE a.at_date is null`

in mysql  a.at_date = null will always return false.